# How can I get a list of the installed programs on a machine, from only the image restored to a folder?

Tags: windows-7

I have a DriveImage XML backup of a computer that I have extracted to a local directory.

How can I see which apps are installed (and where) without booting to it? I can browse it, and obviously look in the Program Files directory, but I want to see the details that you would normally see in "Add/Remove Programs".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open `regedit`
2. Click the HKLM key.
3. File -> Load Hive. Browse to \Windows\System32\Config within the image. Select the "Software" file. Click Open. Name the key something like: `Software_Image1`. Ok.
4. Browse to `HKLM\Software_Image1\Microsoft\Windows\CuttentVersion\Installer`.

You're probably most interested in `UserData\S-1-5-18\Products` (under the above key) where most programs will register their installation (the data that appears in Add/Remove programs).

Comment: @Jason, see edited version.

Comment: I tried to edit the question but I can't make an edit < 6 characters. I found the file in System32, not System